# Windows 8 - switch active routes

Tags: networking, windows-8, routing

I have a LAN connecting all the PCs in an office within 10.0.1.0/24 subnet, and a wireless USB card with a WIFI router as an alternate way to access the Internet. Both adapters use DHCP with default gateway provided. I want to be able to switch routing between the two default gateways so that I can easily switch traffic from one ISP to another in case of either one having troubles. I have written a Powershell script that performs metric adjustment, which works correctly, as displayed by `route print` output. The problem is, even if I assign metric to default gateway routes, or to the interfaces themselves, the `tracert` output still shows traffic being directed through one interface and not the other.

The main constraint is that I am not allowed to reboot the computer to accept interface parameters and recalculate routing. Also the default gateway availability check is always true, so default dynamic routing based on link availability cannot be performed natively. Disabling and enabling adapters is also out of question, because I still need access to other devices on LAN.

How do I change the active route without rebooting the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that restarting `DHCP` service makes network subsystem to recalculate metrics for default routes and use the route with lowest metric set afterwards. So, if someone wants to change default gateways on the fly on Windows, they should do the same. This makes the network connectivity to be dropped for a couple of seconds, so it should not be done interactively.